# Publishing to Amazon S3 with Espresso

Tags: macos, amazon-s3, publish, macrabbit-espresso

I've been looking around to get some clarity on this but it seems like I'm the only stupid one having a problem with it.

Case is, I can't connect to Amazon S3 with Espresso. Or I think the case is rather that I don't know how to. I mean, I have my username, access key and secret key. Espresso asks for the username and password. So which one is my password? What should I use as the "server"? The port? I just can't make it work.

Sorry for being stupid but please help me out here. I know there are many of yous who use both Espresso and Amazon S3.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: So does anybody have an idea about this?

Answer (score 4):

Way old question, but for the ones (like me) who googles it and ends up here, I found out how to make it work:

**Server:** s3.amazonaws.com

**User name:** Your access key

**Password:** Your secret access key